# [Vue.js2]How to use debounce in deep watch in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use `debounce` in `depp watch` but it does not work! And I know it could work in `watch` which without `depp: true`.
Thx!

Comment: share you snippet/live demo where `debounce` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example, https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/eywraw8t/237153/

```
  watch: {
    todos: {
      deep: true,
      handler: _.debounce(function(v) {

      },1000)
    }
  }
```